# Understanding Docker Compose Nginx-Proxy with Docker-Alpine-Python-Flask

Tags: python, docker-compose, uwsgi, alpine-linux, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I have some problem when using Docker.
My problem is understanding reverse proxy when using docker-compose and this library
https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy

so i have 1 Dockerfile like, here :

```
FROM alpine:latest
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    g++ \
    gcc \
    freetds \
    ca-certificates \
    build-base \
    libc-dev \
    python3 \
    python3-dev \
    unixodbc-dev \
    bash \
    nginx \
    uwsgi \
    uwsgi-python3 \
    supervisor && \
    python3 -m ensurepip && \
    rm -r /usr/lib/python*/ensurepip && \
    pip3 install --no-cache-dir --upgrade --force-reinstall pip setuptools && \
    pip3 install -r /tmp/requirements.txt && \
    rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && \
    rm -r /root/.cache

# Copy ODBC Driver
COPY odbc.ini /etc/
COPY odbcinst.ini /etc/

# Copy the Nginx global conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
# Copy the Flask Nginx site conf
COPY flask-site-nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
# Copy the base uWSGI ini file to enable default dynamic uwsgi process number
COPY uwsgi.ini /etc/uwsgi/
# Custom Supervisord config
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf

# Add demo app
COPY ./app /app
# EXPOSE 80

WORKDIR /app

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

when i am run

```
docker build -t name/name . #success
docker run -d --name=container_name -p 80 name/name:latest #success
```

and i am run

```
curl -i localhost/page #success
```

------------ and my problem is understanding when using nginx-proxy ------------------
within port assigned

## 1 Create docker network name reverse-proxy and run jwilder/nginx-proxy

```
docker network create --driver bridge reverse-proxy
docker run -d -p 81:80 -p 444:443 \
    --name reverse-proxy \
    --net=reverse-proxy \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro \
    jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

here my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  atk-request:
    build: ./_atkrequest                 #path which Dockerfile is exists
    container_name: api-atkrequest        
    restart: always
    networks: 
      - reverse-proxy
    # ports:
    #   - 80:80                            #host:container
    expose:
      - 80
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=atkrequest.api.dev  #nginx-proxy host
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=80                  #nginx-proxy port

networks: 
  reverse-proxy:
    external: 
      name: reverse-proxy
```

then run

```
docker-compose up -d #success without error
```

and output docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES
ca95a0f42de2        atkrequest_atk-request   "/usr/bin/supervisord"   5 seconds ago        Up 3 seconds        80/tcp                                     api-atkrequest
c42a9f9d85b5        jwilder/nginx-proxy      "/app/docker-entrypoâ¦"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   reverse-proxy
```

and when call url with curl error code 503 Service Temporary UnAvailable

```
curl -i localhost
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
Server: nginx/1.14.0
Date: Wed, 10 Oct 2018 07:39:09 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 213
Connection: keep-alive

<html>
<head><title>503 Service Temporarily Unavailable</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>503 Service Temporarily Unavailable</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.14.0</center>
</body>
</html>
```

then i am stuck here...

thanks
ik

Answer (score 0):

`jwilder/nginx-proxy` generates an Nginx `default.conf` with entries for each of your containers that have `VIRTUAL_HOST` defined.

Since you have defined `VIRTUAL_HOST=atkrequest.api.dev` on one of your containers, the generated `default.conf` will have something like

```
# atkrequest.api.dev
upstream atkrequest.api.dev {
    ## Can be connected with "{{dir_name}}_default" network
    # {{dir_name}}_atk-request
    server {{atk-request container ip}}:80;
}
server {
    server_name atkrequest.api.dev;
    listen 80 ;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://atkrequest.api.dev;
    }
}
```

But there will nothing configured for `localhost` because none you of containers have `VIRTUAL_HOST=localhost` defined. So when you request arrives to `nginx-proxy` - it responds with `503` as it does not have any configuration for `localhost`.

If you want to keep `nginx-proxy` and be able to access `atk-request` container with `localhost` - change it's environment variable to `VIRTUAL_HOST=localhost`. (Overkill technique, as you can simply expose port `80:80` and not use `nginx-proxy`, but I include it for the explanation)

If you want to access `atk-request` container with `atkrequest.api.dev` - simply add `127.0.0.1 atkrequest.api.dev` to your `/etc/hosts`.